# iTunes Connect: Need to upload a new binary even if there is change in only Metadata and screenshot

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, metadata, appstore-approval

My App got rejected because we didn't provide Demo account for Login. Also the screenshots provided are of only `Launch screen` and `Login/SignUp` pages.

Apple rejected the binary saying:

> 2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user
>   name and password in the App Review Information section for your app
>   in App Store Connect.
>
> 2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata
>
> Please revise your screenshots to ensure that they accurately reflect
>   the app in use on the supported devices

However, to fix this I can provide the functional `Login Account` and the New screenshots depicting the actual content of App.

Still they have asked me for a new binary even if there is no change in the App-side:

> Since your App Store Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be
>   required.

My question is:

**Should I appeal to Apple for using my existing build after I provide the login credentials and updated screenshots?**

**Or do I need to upload a new binary even if there are no changes in it except the build number?**

Comment: Apple have told you, you will need to upload a new build as your current build is rejected.  This will take much less time than opening a case with Apple and waiting for them to respond, where they will probably tell you to upload a new binary anyway.

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, but any specific reason why they want a new binary? Because the new binary which I'll provide will be intact except the build number.

Comment: I think it is because the state is "rejected"; the system won't let you re-submit the same binary.  If it had a status of "metadata-rejected" then you could update the metadata and re-submit the same binary, but they didn't do that.  Maybe they pressed the wrong button.

Comment: @NileshPol This is because of app completeness. if your app met with this, it goes under rejection state. mostly demo acc missing comes under meta-data rejected. but somehow they put you under binary rejected: you can appeal to reconsider.